# Find tree height given preorder

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, depth, preorder

Given a preorder traversal of a full binary tree, where each node is labeled either a leaf node or an internal node, is there a good algorithm to find the height of the tree?  For example, if N represents an internal node and L represents a leaf, then given the preorder traverseal NLNNLLL, the height would be three.

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I hope no one answers this until you say what you've tried and post code and ask more relevant questions... we aren't here to do your homework

Comment: @thiton: the "homework" tag is supposed to be obsolete now, not sure why though. Edit: Here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?newsletter=1&nlcode=95043|8eb5

Comment: I can only think of recreating the tree and finding its depth. But I am sure there is an easier way.

Comment: @marti: How does recreating the tree help you here? You may not be fully understanding what a preorder traversal is.

Comment: There is no ambiguity in your example. The top one is NNLLNLL. The other is NNLNLLL.

Comment: @SauceMaster: if you recreate a tree, you can find out its height.

Comment: Try recreating the tree and its height simultaneously. Then get rid of the tree.

Comment: Well,Its an online judge,i want to do it as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @n.m. My point was that you don't need to recreate the tree to find its depth if you have a preorder traversal, it can be determined fairly easily from a simple counting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I can't help but feel bad that we're leaving marti hanging in the comments. I think he truly doesn't know where to start, and has at least demonstrated that he's thought about the problem.

What do we know about a full binary tree? Each node is either a leaf or has two children.

A preorder traversal recursively visits the root, left subtree, then right subtree.

Think about this question: at what point in the preorder traversal (of a full binary tree) do we know we've exhausted a subtree? We will have visited its root, and then two leaves (or just the root if it's a leaf).

Let's make a stack of a special structure:

```
struct StackNode{
   size_t count; //initialize to 0
   char nodeType; //'N' or 'L'
};
```

This 'StackNode' object will track what type of node we visited in our preorder traversal using the 'nodeType' variable, which should be clear. We also have a special counter 'count' which we initialize to 0.

The idea behind a solution would be this:

- each time you encounter a 'N', create a StackNode, and push it onto the stack.
- each time you encounter a 'L', create a StackNode, and push it onto the stack
- if the last node you pushed onto the stack was 'L', then pop the last node off, and then increment stack.top()'s count by 1
- if stack.top()'s count is 2, then pop the top off the stack, and then increment stack.top()'s count by 1 (repeat until stack is empty or you've stopped popping off the stack)

Every time you push a node onto the stack, you can check the current height of your tree. It is the number of items in your stack-1 (accounting for the item on the bottom being the root).

As long as your track the maximum height you've encountered thus far, you will find the height of your tree.

Let's work through your example: `NLNNLLL`

---

Stack is initially empty.

```
int maxHeight = -1;
```

---

process first character: `N`

push a node onto the stack:

Stack: Type   Count

- N,   0

  maxHeight = 0;

---

process next character: `L`

push a node onto the stack:

- L, 0
- N, 0

  maxHeight = 1; //(incremented by 1)

The last character processed was a leaf, so pop and increment:

stack:

- N, 1

  maxHeight = 1;

---

process next character: `N`

push a node onto the stack:

- N, 0
- N, 1

  maxHeight = 1; //unchanged

---

process next character: `N`

push a node onto the stack:

- N, 0
- N, 0
- N, 1

  maxHeight = 2; //(incremented by 1)

---

process next character: `L`

push a node onto the stack:

- L, 0
- N, 0
- N, 0
- N, 1

  maxHeight = 3; //incremented by 1

last node was a leaf, so pop and increment

stack:

- N, 1
- N, 0
- N, 1

  maxHeight = 3; //unchanged

---

process next character: `L`

push a node onto the stack:

- L, 0
- N, 1
- N, 0
- N, 1

  maxHeight = 3; //unchanged

last node was a leaf, so pop and increment:

- N, 2
- N, 0
- N, 1

top node has count 2, so pop and increment:

- N, 1
- N, 1

---

process next node: `L`

push a node onto the stack:

- L, 0
- N, 1
- N, 1

  maxHeight = 3; //unchanged

last node was a leaf, so pop and increment:

- N, 2
- N, 1

top node has count 2, so pop and increment:

- N, 2

top node has count 2, so pop and increment:

```
(empty stack), finished

maxHeight = 3; //the maximum height discovered during a preorder of a full binary tree
```

Comment: do i actually need to push leaf or just comparing it with node in stack will do??

Comment: coded the solution here http://shrib.com/proo still not accepted by judge.

Comment: @marti: I haven't read through all your code, but one thing you are doing incorrectly is this: int maxh=0; You are instantiating height to 0 instead of -1. When the root node gets pushed onto the tree, height will become 1, which is wrong. When something isn't working, "It's not working" doesn't help us debug. Please at least provide a test input/output to show how it's not working. Even better, find the specific logic that's not working and point us to it.

Comment: A Single value of L results in answer-1 when it should be 0,I push the first node initially at the beginning, and thats why I have the maxh =0 instead of -1.I cannot say why its not working as its an online judge which doesnt reveal testcases.